# How to Pass IHttpContextAccessor as a parameter for crating instance in Activator.createinstance method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to dynamically resolve InstancePerLifetimeScope dependency in ASP.NET Core for this i made method to create instance using Activator.createinstance but i don't know how to pass IHttpContextAccessor as parameter in that.Please suggest how to do it?My code is like below

```
 var type = Type.GetType(ScheduleTask.Type) ??
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .Select(a => a.GetType(ScheduleTask.Type))
            .FirstOrDefault(t => t != null);

            dynamic instance = null;
            try
            {
            instance =Activator.CreateInstance(type,IHttpContextAccesso);
            }
```

Comment: Why dont you register IHttpContextAccessor in IoC container ?

Comment: I did but I want to execute some services dynamically and that services has some other dependency which I resolved using IHttpcontextaccessor. But now to make instances of that service I need to pass IHttpcontextaccessor because of constructor

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed example of your situation? There's a good chance you don't have to use Activator.CreateInstance (Reflection). You might be able to inject the dependencies you need in the constructor or use IServiceProvider to resolve them dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're doing here, but in general, if you need an instance of `IHttpContextAccessor` then you must inject that into the class where this code is.

If this code is not involved in the dependency injection process at all, then it is impossible to get an instance.